# Facebook API no longer supplies emails for user logging in using passport FB Strategy

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm building an express4 app using passport's FB strategy, as well as local logins. I've been capturing the user's email as a way to link local and FB accounts.

Suddenly, (at around the time I created a new test app in FB), I no longer received emails from logins to FB. Given that I'm testing with my own account, there should be no problem. Here's the FB strategy:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: ids.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: ids.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: ids.facebook.callbackURL,
    enableProof: false,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'emails']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile)
    User.findOne({ username: profile.emails[0].value }, function (err, user) {
      if(err) {
        return done(err)
      }
      if (user) {
        // if doesn't contain facebook id, add it
        user.update({facebookId : profile.id}, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err)
          }
        })
        return done(null, user)
      }
      if (! user) {
        User.create({username: profile.emails[0].value, facebookId: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
          if(err) {
            return done(err, null)
          }
          return done(null, user)
        })
      }
    });
  }
));
```

The line that displays the profile now returns this:

```
GET /auth/facebook 302 0.981 ms - 0
{ id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  username: undefined,
  displayName: 'Dan Donaldson',
  name: 
   { familyName: undefined,
     givenName: undefined,
     middleName: undefined },
  gender: undefined,
  profileUrl: undefined,
  provider: 'facebook',
  _raw: '{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","name":"Dan Donaldson"}',
  _json: { id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', name: 'Dan Donaldson' } }
```

Anyone seen this problem? FB no longer provides emails for users logging in for either the main app, or the test app created. I have a feeling this is an FB problem, not a node/js/express/passport problem, since no code changes of any relation to this seemed to be associated....

Comment: I would guess that it is not Facebook fault. And the code doesn't ask for the email field.

Comment: read the changelog if something changes - my guess would be "declarative fields", search for that in the changelog.

Comment: question solved with adding the field specification in the route:

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment above: I added a field specification in the route:

```
router.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email']}));
```

That is in the docs, but there seemed to be some doubt about it being required, and (I think this is the relevant point), the code *did* work without it, on localhost. So I had more or less forgotten about it.

I haven't tested, but it may be that only the route matters, but I have it in both places in any case, and it works fine now.